# PHP loop for JSON rows

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have example array of my data and I have to insert it into Google Charts with json. But I'd like to know how could make each Json data row with loop, so if I don't have that specific value defined I won't get an error.

```
$dataArray=array('item1;item2;item3;item4;item5','item2;item4;item3','item2;item3','item5;item4','item1;item4;item2');

$arrayOUT = [];
  foreach ($dataArray as $a) {
    $t = explode(";", $a);

    foreach ($t as $y) {
      if (!isset($arrayOUT[$y])) {
        $arrayOUT[$y] = 0;

      }
        $arrayOUT[$y] += 1;
    }
  }
```

At the moment I have static json rows:

```
echo '{
  "cols": [
        {"id":"","label":"Data","pattern":"","type":"string"},
        {"id":"","label":"Count","pattern":"","type":"number"}
      ],
  "rows": [
        {"c":[{"v":"item1","f":null},{"v":'.$arrayOUT['item1'].',"f":null}]},
        {"c":[{"v":"item2","f":null},{"v":'.$arrayOUT['item2'].',"f":null}]},
        {"c":[{"v":"item3","f":null},{"v":'.$arrayOUT['item3'].',"f":null}]},
        {"c":[{"v":"item4","f":null},{"v":'.$arrayOUT['item4'].',"f":null}]},
        {"c":[{"v":"item5","f":null},{"v":'.$arrayOUT['item5'].',"f":null}]}
      ]
}';
```

But I would like to have rows done with loop. So for example, if I dont have item4 in my array, it wont create this row. So it only creates rows with existing data.

```
echo '{
  "cols": [
        {"id":"","label":"Data","pattern":"","type":"string"},
        {"id":"","label":"Count","pattern":"","type":"number"}
      ],
  "rows": [
```

Loop this row to create dynamic rows
            {"c":[{"v":"item","f":null},{"v":'.$arrayOUT['item'].',"f":null}]},

```
      ]
}';
```

Comment: Please don't create JSON by hand, use PHP's `json_encode()` to create your JSON from arrays that you build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a loop over the arrayOUT object.
I edited your example:

```
$dataArray=array('item1;item2;item3;item4;item5','item2;item4;item3','item2;item3','item5;item4','item1;item4;item2');

$arrayOUT = [];

foreach ($dataArray as $a) {
    $t = explode(";", $a);

    foreach ($t as $y) {
        if (!isset($arrayOUT[$y])) {
            $arrayOUT[$y] = 0;

        } else {
            $arrayOUT[$y] += 1;
        }
    }
}

$rows = "";

forEach($arrayOUT as $item=>$count){
    $rows = $rows."{'c':[{'v':'{$item}','f':null},{'v':'{$count}','f':null}]},";
}

echo '{
  "cols": [
        {"id":"","label":"Data","pattern":"","type":"string"},
        {"id":"","label":"Count","pattern":"","type":"number"}
      ],
  "rows": [
        '.$rows.'
      ]
}';
```